# If statements and strings error

Tags: swift, if-statement

I Have

```
  if rockNamesArray == "rock2" {
    let firstPos: CGFloat = 300.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.mrock.frame = CGRectMake(167, 600, CGFloat(self.mrock.bounds.size.width), CGFloat(self.mrock.bounds.size.height))
    })}
```

as well as

```
var rockNamesArray:[String ] = ["bird", "rock2", "rock3"]

var rockpos = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))

var firstrockString:String = rockNamesArray[rockpos]
```

But its telling me I can't use "==" for the if statement. What would I use in place for it. "rock2" is a string

Comment: if rocksNamesArray is an array then you cannot compare it to a string

Comment: Like giorashc said, `rocksNamesArray` is an Array. What exactly do you want to compare? If `rocksNamesArray` contains `"rock2"` or else you'll have to specify which index of the `rocksNamesArray` you want to compare.

Comment: What they said, an array stores multiple string variables so you want rockNamesArray[2]

Comment: The array assigns a value to each of the images that I put in the array right? So I want it to be that if the RNG generates 1, it generates 1, then it moves the image that is assigned the value 1.

Comment: you may need to enumerate through the array's _items_, and each individual _item_ can be compared to `"rock2"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if `"rock2"` is inside the array:

```
if contains(rockNamesArray, "rock2") {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Or if you want to check a certain index of the array and compare it to `"rock2"` with `n` being the index:

```
var rockNamesArray:[String ] = ["bird", "rock2", "rock3"]
var rockpos = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))

if rockNamesArray[rockpos] == "rock2" {
    let firstPos: CGFloat = 300.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0) {
        self.mrock.frame = CGRectMake(167, 600, CGFloat(self.mrock.bounds.size.width), CGFloat(self.mrock.bounds.size.height))
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this but it what I want to do is make so that the RNG picks a number, 0, 1, or 2, and then move the image down the screen. I what you have with the if rockNamesArray[n] but it just moves them all. The Array and stuff isn't in the view controller or anything, and the animations are in the viewdidappear func